# Ms crm 2011 dashboard increase row count via JavaScript or plugin

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Is there any way to increase the number of records that are displayed in a subgrid located on the Dashboard using JavaScript?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: is there a reason you don't just want to increase the size of the grid via the built-in editor?

Comment: We found increasing the row size required more space on the form. We wanted to increase the row count while keeping the grid size constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we decided against displaying the subgrid on the dashboard due to other constraints. see this post -

[crm 2011 hide and show subgrids on dashboard with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29202722/crm-2011-hide-and-show-subgrids-on-dashboard-with-javascript][1])

However, this article might be useful for someone who wants to increase the row count of the subgrid, while keeping it's height constant -

http://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/paul-nieuwelaars-blog/2012/05/17/dynamics_crm_2011_sub_grids_with_more_rows_and_scroll_bar