# crm 2011 hide and show subgrids on dashboard with javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have two subgrids on my dashboard which are vertically aligned. I am able to hide or show either subgrid, however when I hide the top subgrid, the bottom grid does not move to the top, there is an empty space where the grid use to be.
I would like to both grids appear in the same location on the page as they are shown or hidden.

I have the code below to hide/show:

```
setVisible('subgrid1_d', false);
setVisible('subgrid2_d', true);

function setVisible(id, show){

   if (show == true)
        $('#' + id).show();
  else
        $('#' + id).hide();
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your subgrids in different sections and show and hide the section where the subgrid is.

Remember that using jquery to access the form elements it is not supported, you should always use the Xrm.Page.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It appears that the dashboard can only contain a single section. There is no way to add a second section to the form (that I can see). Also, I have to access the grids via jquery because the Xrm.Page.data and Xrm.Page.ui are not set in the dashboard and are by default null.

Comment: Uh, sorry, that changes a little bit the things, that's then only way I know to hide and show reordering.